# Question in separable polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, definition

Let me ask something about separable polynomials. I found the following definitions:

1. A polynomial over $F$ is called *separable* if it has no multiple roots  (i.e. all its roots are distinct). (Dummit & Foote)
2. A polynomial over $F$ is called *separable* if every irreducible factor has not multiple roots (the irreducible factors may not be distinct. (Rotman)

**My question is:** Are these two definitions equivalent? Let me give an example which looks strange:

Lets take the polynomial $f(x)= (x^2-2)^n \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$, with $n\in \Bbb{N}^{\geq 2}$. Then, according to def. 1
$$f(x)=(x-\sqrt2)^n(x+\sqrt2)^n $$
so the roots are multiple, so it is not separable over $\Bbb{Q}$. But, according to def. 2
$$f(x)= \underbrace{(x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)\cdots (x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)\,}_\text{$n$ times} $$
so no one of the irreducible factors has root with multiplicity $=1$. So, it is separable over $\Bbb{Q}$.

How can this happen? Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: I assume you are paraphrasing Dummit & Foote, since I can't make any sense of "multiple roots which are distinct" -- either they're the same or they're not, being both is a tricky proposition.

Comment: See now. It's exactly what they write.

Comment: The previous equivalent question has "A polynomial over $F$ is said to be separable if it has no multiple roots. (given in Dummit & Foote)"

Comment: With $K = \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$ then $x^p-t^p \in K[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $t$ is not separable because there are no primitive $p$-th roots of unity in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$